# Adding Item in Android 4.2 Quick Settings Panel

Tags: android

I just want to make a Battery Temperature Monitor
and display it in Quick Settings Panel like in Google+ .

Is it possible to add an item on it? How?

[image]

Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**: Changed "New Notification Bar" to "Quick Settings Panel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the quick settings panel, not the notifications panel. Google+ is not permitted to modify or add to this panel and neither is any other downloaded app.

The profile image shown is part of the specialized "Me" profile created by the system that the G+ app syncs contact information into. The G+ app is not able to define this tile or the action taken when you tap on it from this panel. The contact card shown when you tap the profile icon is hosted by the system's People app which any other app can inject contact data into, not the G+ app.

Comment: Meaning there's no methods or classes to achieve it? I have seen the "Me" profile in People app.

Comment: No, there's not. If you want to modify the quick settings panel to add new tiles you would have to modify SystemUI.apk and replace it on the /system partition of a device. You cannot do this with an app downloaded from Play Store or similar.

Comment: But the ADM app has this feature you can add but i don't know how