# Add icon to Android's Quick Settings

Tags: android, settings, android-4.4-kitkat

My question is [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774353/adding-item-in-android-4-2-quick-settings-panel). I'm running Android 4.4 on my device, and want to add additional options to the quick settings. I noticed that turning on/off the Alarm Clock shows/hides a tile in the quick settings, like this:

[image: Alarm Clock Off][image: Alarm Clock On]

The biggest difference in the two questions is I want to know what it would take to make it work, either having the device rooted, or flashing a custom app at install or what. I've been trying to browse the source code [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/tree/master/src/com/android/alarmclock), but so far I haven't seen anything that stands out to me.

Sorry about the picture size, I don't know if there's an option to scale them down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to be rooted. I have not come across anything that will let you add tiles under completely stock android. Depending on your phone, you might be able to root it without voiding the warranty explicitly, however it will be tricky. After which you can look at installing something xposed framework and then different xposed modules (I suggest gravity box as it lets you add most options to the quick settings). But again, it's all at your own risk for voiding your warranty or soft-bricking your phone. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Android N introduced Quick Settings API which allow application to add status icon in quick settings. Please check [Android N preview document](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#tile_api) to learn more.

Comment: While a few years late (I can't even remember why I wanted the feature now...), this certainly looks promising!